# How to assign mm/dd/yyyy records to associated Fiscal month found in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

Note: this question is for both SQL and ORACLE and we do not have permissions for creation of temp table or stored procedures.

The database has two tables.

One table has a field of End Dates of Months along with a text field which identifies the "Fiscal Month" label.

Second table has dates by day (mm/dd/yyyy) with numeric data associated.

We need to retrieve the second table data (summing the numerics) grouping by the associated "Fiscal Month" found in table One.

Within one query or using CTE or a better solution, how to perform some kind of lookup on Table One to retrieve the Fiscal Month that the mm/dd/yyy date in Table two should be grouped on.

**Table 1 (Fiscal Month End Dates)**

2015-05-29 - Fiscal Month is 'May2015'

2015-06-30  - Fiscal Month is 'Jun2015'

2015-07-31 - Fiscal Month is 'Jul2015'

**Table 2 (mm/dd/yyyy) which needs to be summed and grouped by Fiscal Month**

2015-05-29 should be grouped on 'May2015'

2015-06-30 should be grouped on 'Jun2015'

Comment: you are contradicting yourself. One time you said format is `mm/dd/yyyy` and when you show the data is `YYYY-MM-DD`. Which is it ??

Answer (score 0):

So the approach I have used is to create a range of dates for a particular fiscal month.
Since you have the last dates of each fiscal month, you can get the previous one as the  end of the previous fiscal month. Of course this is with a starting hard-limit because the first month in the fiscal month table will not have the previous month date (I used 1st of Jan of the year).

Then when you join it with your daily data, you can use these two dates to determine which fiscal month the data belongs to.

To get the previous fiscal month end date, we can use the `LAG` analytic function using the month to order the rows.
The rest of the query is pretty straightforward.

```
WITH
    fiscal_end_dates
    AS
        (SELECT TO_DATE ('2015-05-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS last_date FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_DATE ('2015-06-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS last_date FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_DATE ('2015-07-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS last_date FROM DUAL),
    daily_data
    AS
        (SELECT TO_DATE ('2015-05-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS data_date,
                10 AS some_value
         FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_DATE ('2015-05-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS data_date,
                14 AS some_value
         FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_DATE ('2015-06-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS data_date,
                34 AS some_value
         FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_DATE ('2015-07-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS data_date,
                34 AS some_value
         FROM DUAL),
    fiscal_date_range
    AS
        (SELECT last_date,
                NVL (
                    LAG (last_date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT (MONTH FROM last_date)),
                    TO_DATE (EXTRACT (YEAR FROM last_date) || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                )
                    AS prev_month_fiscal_end_date,
                INITCAP (TO_CHAR (last_date, 'MON')) || EXTRACT (YEAR FROM last_date)
                    AS fiscal_month
         FROM fiscal_end_dates)
SELECT dd.*,
       fdr.fiscal_month
FROM daily_data dd,
     fiscal_date_range fdr
WHERE dd.data_date > fdr.prev_month_fiscal_end_date
      AND dd.data_date <= fdr.last_date;
```

This is the result (I took the liberty of adding a few more rows in your daily data table just to show the query working)

```
DATA_DATE   SOME_VALUE  FISCAL_MONTH
5/29/2015   10          May2015
5/30/2015   14          Jun2015
6/20/2015   34          Jun2015
7/4/2015    34          Jul2015
```

All you need to do now is to use the result set and perform your grouping and aggregation.

Comment: This is great. Thanx. We will try and incorporate this into the ORACLE query version which also includes several other tables we need for additional information. I realize this will not work in SQL Server as there are functions in your example not applicable in SQL Server.

Comment: I'm sure you can find equivalent functions in SQL Server as well. I know it supports `LAG`, there should  be similar functions for `INITCAP`, `DATE` to `CHAR` and getting the month from a DATE.

Comment: Please do mark the answer as helpful if you find it so